# KdV equation and algebraic geometry

Tags: algebraic-geometry, partial-differential-equations

I want to understand how we can use material from algebraic geometry (varieties, ideals, etc) to talk about solitons if at all. My knowledge of algebraic geometry is up to chapter 5 of Ideals, Varities, and Algorithms by Cox et al. and I am hoping to use the KdV equaiton as starting off point.

The KdV: $u_t + u_{xxx}+6uu_x =0$

A wonderful fact is that to show a soliton exists for the KdV we can show that a homoclinic orbit exists. Since the corresponding Hamiltonian is a polynomial, this is what has got me thinking if we can talk this in the framework of algebraic geometry in some way.

I would really appreciate guidance.

Comment: Mi knowledge about AG is very poor, but I can point out that the KdV equation plays an important role in abelian varieties, because it helped to solve the Schottky problem, as you can see [here](https://www.dima.unige.it/didattica/dottorato/wp-content/uploads/2015/11/Alberto_Tacchella.pdf)

Comment: Maybe you want to have a look at "Algebro-Geometric Approach to Nonlinear Integrable Equations" by Belokolos and coauthors. Otherwise (but much harder) "Non-linear equations of Korteweg-de Vries type, finite-zone linear operators, and Abelian varieties." by Dubrovin, Matveev and Novikov. Guess it depends, what exactly you are looking for. Anyways, the references in the two sources I mentioned might help you to get you started.

Comment: The KdV hierarchy comes up somewhere in Mirror Symmetry.

Comment: I don't know what Mirror Symmetry is, but if you have sufficient detail to provide (and time), I encourage you to give an Answer!

Thank you rebo and Severin, I will investigate.